# shuffle error in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

Hi i get the following error in my cluster when i tried to execute a mapreduce program in hadoop. This code works fine for data which had lesser file size but hadoop throws the following error and i have sufficient place in the cluster. I tried increasing heapspace of reducer from 6gb to 10gb and still it fails.
Tag used

Please help me to fix this issue

> Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError:
>   error in shuffle in fetcher#7 at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
>   by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:56)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:46)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.InMemoryMapOutput.(InMemoryMapOutput.java:63)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.unconditionalReserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.reserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:295)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyMapOutput(Fetcher.java:514)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyFromHost(Fetcher.java:336)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:193)

Comment: Did you also increased the reducer memory? mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb

Comment: yes i have increased the reducer memory mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb from 6gb to 10gb

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of the jvm using `mapreduce.[mapper/reducer].java.pts`param. A value around 80-85% of the reducer/mapper memory is suggested. 
Note there is no direct Hadoop 2 equivalent for the first of these; the advice in the source code is to use the other two. mapred.child.java.opts is still supported (but is overridden by the other two more-specific settings if present).

Comment: Just a typo there: 
mapreduce.[mapper/reducer].java.opts 
-server -Xmx{mem}m

Answer (score 0):

Your question would have been more clearer if you have mentioned the Map Reduce properties which you are using for your code to run as it will provide some insights for the memory calculation for the shuffle phase.

memorylimit = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()*(mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent).

The defualt value of mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent is 0.9 and you can decrease its value to 0.2 for your memoryLimit to be < 1. So properties you can include are :

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent</name>
    <value>0.20</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies</name>
    <value>4</value>
</property>
```

For more clarification you can refer : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-6447